# Value of cell that depends on another dynamic cell within a range

Tags: excel, vba

Range A1:A5 is filled with dynamic data, though the data is limited to 5 values, the sequence could differ. It is also possible that only 4 or less is presented. The values are also unique.

Column B's value will depend on Column A.

Example:

```
   A     B
1 item2  USD18
2 item1  USD15
3 item3  USD4
4 item5  USD23
5 item4  USD11
```

How do I accomplish this on VBA?

Comment: Well there are a couple things to consider here. What exactly do you mean by "the sequence could differ"? Will there also be more than these 5 rows or will there be more? If there is more and there are more than 26 what will you do with the letters? Make them become `Y,Z,AA,AB,AC etc`

Comment: How do you get `USD18` from `item2`?

Comment: @Simon I edited my question. The order of the items in Column A is dynamic. It could vary but only the 5 items will still be listed. It is also possible that 4 or less items will be listed.

Comment: @GSerg, It's a static value. That's my struggle, how do I search the range for the item then fill in the cell beside it with a static value. Then loop the whole process for A1:A5

Comment: So this new edit. if I'm understanding correctly. Column A will change around the order of `itemX` and the `USDXX` will match to the item whichever row it is on?

Comment: @Simon Yes, that is right.

Comment: It would appear you want to have a static table that establishes correspondence between each `item` and its `USD`, and put [`=VLOOKUP(A1, static_table, 2, false)`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) in B1:B5.

Comment: @Dumont I've updated my answer. See if that is what you're after.

Comment: You have described values in column A both as "static" and as "dynamic". You have replied the question "How do you get `USD18` from `item2`?" with "It's a static value", presumably referring to "USD18" which wasn't "USD18" in the first version of your question. But if "USD18" is a static value how do you arrive at "Item2" from it? I still think that my approach below has the answer in it. You just aren't helpful in finding it. Take a look. You are giving us a static list that is changing and dynamic values without rules how to relate them to each other. Please work on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced my answer with the one below from your edit which completely changed things.

See if this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim ValueArr As Variant

ValueArr = Array("USD15", "USD18", "USD4", "USD11", "USD23")

For i = 1 To 5
    If Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
        Range("B" & i) = ValueArr(Right(Range("A" & i), 1) - 1)
    End If
Next i
```

This code is based off of using the number on the end of `item` to know which value to put in place. If the row is blank it will skip over it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite tricky. Please try this code after adjusting the items marked "change to suit".

```
Sub SetSequence()
    ' 156

    Const DataClm   As Long = 2             ' change to suit (2 = column B)
    Const ItemClm   As Long = 1             ' change to suit (1 = column A)
    
    Dim Wb          As Workbook
    Dim Ws          As Worksheet
    Dim DataRng     As Range                ' sorted given data (column B in your example)
    Dim Results     As Variant              ' results: sorted 1 to 5
    Dim TmpClm      As Long                 ' a column temporarily used by this macro
    Dim Tmp         As String               ' working string
    Dim R           As Long                 ' oop counter: rows
    Dim i           As Long                 ' index of Results
    
    Results = Array("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", _
                    "Item4", "Item5")       ' modify list items as required (sorted!)
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook                   ' modify as needed
    Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")        ' change to suit
    With Ws
        With .UsedRange
            TmpClm = .Column + .Columns.Count
        End With
        
        ' create a copy of your data (without header) in an unused column
        .Range(.Cells(2, DataClm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, DataClm).End(xlUp)) _
               .Copy .Cells(1, TmpClm)
        Set DataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, TmpClm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, TmpClm).End(xlUp))
        
        With .Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add2 Key:=Ws.Cells(1, TmpClm), _
                  SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, _
                  DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        With .Sort
            .SetRange DataRng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        
        ' blanks are removed, if any
        Set DataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, TmpClm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, TmpClm).End(xlUp))
        ' start in row 2 of DataClm and look at next 5 cells
        For R = 2 To 6
            ' skip over blanks
            Tmp = .Cells(R, DataClm).Value
            If Len(Trim(Tmp)) Then
                i = WorksheetFunction.Match(Tmp, DataRng, 0)
                .Cells(R, ItemClm).Value = Results(i - 1)
            End If
        Next R
        .Columns(TmpClm).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

The code creates a sorted copy of the items you have in column B and draws the output in column A from the similarly sorted list of results. Blanks are ignored. But if there is one blank in the input list (column B) there will be only 4 items in the sorted input list and therefore none of the items can be assigned "Item 5" in column A.